# Большая сцена для динамических объектов

Tags: android

Требуется создать сцену  неопределенных размеров, динамически расширяемую при добавлении нового объекта. Количество добавляемых объектов неограниченно. Сцена двухмерная.
Посоветуйте, как эту сцену лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать массив (или список) с объектами и их координатамим. Изменять размер сцены при добавлении нового объекта (изменять размер, если новый объект вышел за координаты сцены). Отрисовывать только те объекты, которые попали в поле видимости камеры (нужно перепроверять видимость каждый кадр, или 1 раз на несколько кадров).

Comment: А в каком Layout все это будет удобней сделать? или может не Layout. Саму сцену на каком компоненте лучше делать?

Comment: Ну раз координаты есть, и положения экрана есть. То лучше всего frame_layout, где отступы от левого и верхнего края будут координатами.

Comment: @Raaur Скорее всего у вас просто будет поле растянутое на весь экран, а границы сцены будут виртуальными(например можете рисовать бортики по краям или еще что-то. Если отрисовывать будете через OpenGL, то подойдет SurfaceView, растянутый на весь экран. http://habrahabr.ru/post/126316/

Comment: SurfaceView  предполагает 3D. а в данном случае достаточно 2D. но всеравно спс за материал

Comment: @Raaur не предполагает 3Д. Можете как 2д так и 3д выбрать, в зависимости как хотите рисовать. Там нет ограничений на это.

Comment: понял спс. буду разбираться и с ним